# Create matched tasks based on variables in a file with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm not sure if Ansible is the right way to do this, but here's what I need to do:
I have a file with a list of 2 columns (Host IP | Mac Address), and I want to run an ansible playbook to match the host IP with my host IP file. When the host IP is matched, then run the task oh "show mac address" for that matched host.
How can I go about this? It would be a "loop" and and "if statement". Not sure how to combine both in Ansible

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't read the MAC address directly from the host gathered facts ? This is available in `ansible_<ifname>.macaddress`. Else, you can read your csv (I guess...) file in with the [`read_csv` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/read_csv_module.html) and quite easilly match the element having the corresponding IP to read its macaddress. You would need to provide some examples and some code tries to go further.

Comment: Because it's to locate the ports of Mac address that fall in the catch all of the dot1x. I need to find their ports based on the file list

Answer (score 1):

As explained in my comments, your question IMO lacks some examples and trials from your side to fully get what you are trying to achieve and how. Meanwhile, making some assumptions, here is a simple example to maybe put you on track.

I will assume your ip/mac file is a csv like file (or easilly transformable to that format). This is the file I used for tests:

**data.csv**

```
1.1.1.1,aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa
2.2.2.2,bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb
```

I needed some fake inventory to run against. This the test one again

**inventory.ini**

```
test1.local ansible_host=1.1.1.1
test2.local ansible_host=2.2.2.2
```

Last, this is the playbook that, I believe, does the job your are waiting for. Of course I play it against my fake inventory above and I get the IP I set myself in `ansible_host`. You will have to adapt to your real life situation.

**test.yml**

```
---
- name: read our ref file
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: read ref csv for future use
      read_csv:
        fieldnames:
          - ip
          - macaddress
        key: ip
        path: data.csv
      register: my_data

    - name: Show how our var looks like 
      debug:
        var: my_data.dict

- name: Get mac depending on host IP
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    my_mac_info: "{{ hostvars.localhost.my_data.dict }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Show macaddress in file for current ip
      debug:
        msg: "Current host is {{ inventory_hostname }} with ip {{ ansible_host }}. Lookup macaddress is {{ my_mac_info[ansible_host].macaddress }}"
```

And here is the result:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini test.yml 

PLAY [read our ref file] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [read ref csv for future use] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show how our var looks like] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_data.dict": {
        "1.1.1.1": {
            "ip": "1.1.1.1",
            "macaddress": "aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"
        },
        "2.2.2.2": {
            "ip": "2.2.2.2",
            "macaddress": "bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb"
        }
    }
}

PLAY [Get mac depending on host IP] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show macaddress in file for current ip] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test1.local] => {
    "msg": "Current host is test1.local with ip 1.1.1.1. Lookup macaddress is aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"
}
ok: [test2.local] => {
    "msg": "Current host is test2.local with ip 2.2.2.2. Lookup macaddress is bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test1.local                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test2.local                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```